# Change name in every iteration in Python in order to save

Tags: python, variables, iteration

I was wondering how can i change the name of a file inside a for loop in order to save it with different consecutive names. e.g

```
for i in range(0, np.max(idx)+1):    
    vars()['cluster' + str(i)]= [tracks[x] for x in range(len(tracks)) if idx[x] == i]
    function_to_write("/Users/George/Desktop/file.bmp", vars()['cluster' + str(i)])
```

How can i change the FileName in order to be file1, file2 etc ?

Comment: why are you using vars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it as follows:

```
"/Users/George/Desktop/file{0}.bmp".format(i+1)
```

This uses python's `string.format(...)` method which replaces the `{}` with the specified value.

The `{0}` means that the value to replace this will be the 0th argument (1st position) in `format(...)`

Furthermore, I see you are using `vars()` which means you probably have variables stored as `cluster1`, `cluster2`, `cluster3`, ...

This is generally not a good idea and instead, it is recommended that you use a `list`.

If you store all your "clusters" in one list called `clusters`, you can then instead do:

```
for i in range(0, np.max(idx)+1):
    clusters[i] = [tracks[x] for x in range(len(tracks)) if idx[x] == i]
    function_to_write("/Users/George/Desktop/file{0}.bmp".format(i+1), clusters[i])
```

Comment: yep, better to use enumerate also

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, np.max(idx) + 1):
    filename = "file%d.bmp" % i + 1
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `format` or `%s` in a list comprehension :

```
[function_to_write("/Users/George/Desktop/file{}.bmp".format(i), vars()['cluster' + str(i)]) for i in range(1,n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add every `i` to file name like this:

```
function_to_write("/Users/George/Desktop/file"+str(i)+".bmp", vars()['cluster' + str(i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

version using f string.

```
for i in range(0, np.max(idx) + 1):
    filename = f'/Users/George/Desktop/file{i + 1}.bmp'
```